# Recognizing text file Form Feeds in MigraDoc

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

Is there a way for MigraDoc to recognize form feeds characters that are already embedded in a ASCII text file? Or does one have to process the text file line by line to catch them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that "form feeds" are treated as page breaks by MigraDoc automatically.

The output probably looks better if you process the text file anyway (e.g. treat single CR/LF as spaces only, treat empty lines as new paragraphs, etc.).

It could even make sense to ignore the form feeds - the text files probably weren't made for proportional fonts. If you use proportional fonts with MigraDoc (e.g. Arial), the documents could fit on a smaller number of pages.

Comment: I can't ignore them because the text file is preformatted using a fixed point font to display a table layout on letter paper. Strange that "CR/LF" are recognized but not form feeds.  Anyways, I got it working by reading in each line and doing a doc.LastSection.AddPageBreak() + doc.LastSection.AddParagraph() when I run across a form feed character.